# Muting previousState to set the new State in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, splice

I'm changing a state in React based on a previousState. Basically I'm removing an item from an array of items and I want the best simplest way.

This works perfectly, but maybe not the best practice?

```
handleItemsRemove = (id, index) => {
    if (index === -1) {
      return;
    }
    this.setState(
      previousState => {
        const { items } = previousState;
        items.splice(index, 1);
        return {
          items
        };
      }
    );
  };
```

Is there any issues regarding this code that concerns mutability etc in React way of reworking previousState? Is `previousState` mutable, and even if so, is it OK to do so?

Otherwise what do you consider best way of handling such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) modifies original array - so this is not the way you need.

Instead you can filter out an unneeded item. Please read more about [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method which creates a new array.

Also you don't need to create a variable for the whole state. Instead you can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
handleItemsRemove = (id, index) => {
  if (index === -1) {
    return;
  }

  this.setState(({items}) => ({
    items: items.filter((item, itemIndex) => index !== itemIndex),
  }));
};
```

Comment: The thing I don't like with this solution is that it loops through the entire array, whereas I already know where to remove.

Answer (score 1):

From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state):

> Never mutate `this.state` directly, as calling `setState()` afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat `this.state` as if it were immutable.

I'm not sure if that applies to your situation, but build up an entirely new object to be safe. You can use `items.slice(0, index)` to get the part of the array before `index` and `items.slice(index + 1)` for the part after `index`, then [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals) them over a new array:

```
handleItemsRemove = (id, index) => {
  if (index === -1) {
    return;
  }
  this.setState(
    ({items}) => ({
      items: [
        ...items.slice(0, index),
        ...items.slice(index + 1)
      ]
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: So it does. I was thinking of Redux.

Comment: oh I se.. I don't use Redux :) But as you are using `setState`, so you can 100% rely that state will be merged, no need to spread others..which were not changed from this place.

Comment: I have deleted my answer, but I can help you with another idea.. Instead of creating so many intermediate arrays.. Do `previousState.items.slice().splice(index, 1)`... it is more clean and faster..

Comment: @ArupRakshit great answer. You should add this as a new answer. I think it's actually the best